# Point construction - one point equal to several points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, geometric-construction

I have been studying point constructions from ruler and compass in context to field extensions. I follow the proofs without too much trouble, but there is a simple note I do not follow.

In *A Book of Basic Abstract Algebra* by *Charles C. Pinter* a point $P$ is defined to be **constructible** from a set of points $A$ in a plane if there are points $P_1 , P_2, ... , P_i = P$ such that $P_1$ is constructible in one step from $A$ and $P_2$ is constructible in one step from $A \cup P_1$ and so on til $P_i$ is constructible in one step from $A \cup \{P_1 , ... , P
_i \}$

I was hoping someone could help me explain how we can define one point to be several points? It is: $ \space $ **$P_1 , P_2, ... , P_i = P$** $ \space $ I am referring to.

In advance; thank you :D

Comment: It is not the case that one point is defined as several points. I assume you read the expression as $(P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_i)=P$, but it is intended as $(P_1),(P_2),\ldots,(P_i=P)$, i.e. the equality only refers to $P=P_i$. This makes sense, too: You construct new points until at the $i$-th step, you reach $P$.

Comment: Thank you @StefanAlbrecht , that would make perfect sense!!